# Creating a new column by applying a function in an existing column in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark

Say I have a dataframe

```
product_id customers
1 [1,2,4]
2 [1,2]
```

I want to create a new column, say `nb_customer` by applying the function `len` on the column `customers`.

I tried

```
df = df.select('*', (map(len, df.customers)).alias('nb_customer'))
```

but it does not work.

What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = sc.parallelize([
    [1,[1,2,4]],
    [2,[1,2]]
]).toDF(('product_id', 'customers'))

df.withColumn('nb_customer',f.size(df.customers)).show()
```